# Using custom ID3-Tags in iTunes (OS X)

Tags: macos, itunes, id3

I love foobar2000 on Windows and have 2 custom Tags for my mp3s - Rate and mood.

Now I have to use a Mac to play my music and emulating foobar won't work, because foobar has to recreate its database every time it starts... and thats about 2h of hashing - no good.

So is there any way to read out, order by and write custom tags with iTunes or any other, if possible free, Mac app?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Kid3](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/) as this application is an Open Source ID3 Tag createror.